# Send 2 or more messages in WA with one Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, message, whatsapp

I know how to make a Intent for send a message in WhatsApp:

```
public void onClickWhatsApp(View view) {
Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
waIntent.setType("text/plain");
String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";
waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
if (waIntent != null) {
    waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

But.. im interested to send 2 or more message in the same intent. ¿How can I do it?

Comment: Did this come from: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15931345/2 originally?